# How do I make a project in Django? Beginner

Tags: django

Okay I just started with Django and it's totally different from PHP. 
I installed Python 2.6 and Django.

Both are located in my C drive.

```
C:
   Django
          build
          django
             bin
               django-admin.py
          docs
   Python26
```

I am doing the [django site tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/#intro-tutorial01) and when they say to write **django-admin.py startproject mysite** from my Python command line, I getting errors.

My django-admin.py is in the django/bin folder. I installed Python via python setup.py. 
How do I create a project with django?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got to run that from a command line, not within the python interpreter!

From the docs:

> From **the command line**, cd  into a
>   directory where you’d like to store
>   your code, then run the command
>   django-admin.py startproject  mysite.
>   This will create a mysite  directory
>   in your current directory.

So from the C prompt:

```
python django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

You might need to add the path to django-admin

Comment: my django-admin.py is in C>django>django>bin. When I run the script, I keep getting 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command...

Comment: wow instantdjango works prefectly!!! What's the difference between that and python/django from the offical site?

Comment: Well that bundles Python and sorts out all the paths (something I suspect you hadn't done). Windows is rubbish.

Comment: I'm sure Python and Django is installed correctly. I can run from the IDLE and when I run "import django and django.VERSION" on the python command line, it works. Do I have to put Python in the Django folder? Or should they both be in separate folders?

Comment: check your system PATH, and maybe you can use python.exe instead python

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have not added C:\python26 or wherever you have installed your python to the PATH .... you can edit the path from cmd or by right-clicking My Computer and going to environment variable tab from properties...add both python path and django path where u have your admin.py

Answer (score 0):

it is very easy to make  a python django project
run terminal in you linux or mac box
**first:**

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

mysite is a project name

**second:**
in python django project, each and every feature should be start in an app, so our next work is create a app. here **polls** is a app
entered your project folder and run

```
python manage.py startapp polls
python manage.py syncdb
```

then just run the project
python default run on `8000` port. you also define port like this way

```
python manage.py runserver 6006
```

go your browser and hit `http://127.0.0.1:6006`

next step is configure the project and manage the project. you have to change some change in `settings.py` and `urls.py`

Answer (score 0):

Your virtual Environment will contain these three folder: 
1)Include 
2)Lib 
3) Scripts 
(Read about them from django official website) 
What you need to do is use all these 3 things.
On your command line `cd` into your virtual environment folder.Then use this code:
 
python Scripts\django-admin.py startproject mysite

Output: A folder named "mysite" will be created inside your virtual environment.And because this folder is inside virtual environment, you will be able to use all 3 components.

Answer (score 0):

**Boilerplate Code**
To create django as well create django app you have to follow many common commands.
for simplicity, kindly follow the below single-line commands separated by semicolon:

```
django-admin startproject project_name; cd project_name;python3 manage.py startapp app_name; cd app_name; mkdir templates
```

Those commands will create commonly used structure for django.

Answer (score 0):

**Create a virtual environment**

```
python3 -m venv my-env
```

**Activate the my-env**

```
Source my-env/bin/activate
```

**Install Django in my-env**

```
pip install django
```

**Check the version**

```
django-admin --version
```

**Crarte folder in my-project**

```
 $ cd my-project
```

**Then**

```
$ django-admin startproject my-project-name
$ cd my-project-name
$ python manage.py runserver
```

**Then open browser and type url**
http://127.0.0.1:8000/
or
http://localhost:8080